# Ограничить количество созданных внутренних форм(MDI)

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне необходимо привести приложение к виду многооконного интерфейса (MDI).
Я хочу, чтобы количество внутренних окон не было больше заданного числа.

```
  public class GenericSingleton<T> where T : Form, new()
    {

        private static T[] t = new T[4];

        public static T CreateInstrance(int index)
        {
            if (null == t[index] || t[index].IsDisposed)
            {
                t = new T[index];
            }
            if (Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Count(openForm => openForm.IsMdiChild) > 8)
                return null;
            return t[index];
        }
        
    }


    private void formToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f = GenericSingleton<Form>.CreateInstrance(1);
            f.Show();
        }
```

Я написал это, но это не работает. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибки.

Comment: А вы попробуйте прочитать код внутри метода `CreateInstance`: _Если элемент по индексу `null` или он `IsDisposed`, то создать новый массив из `index` элементов._ Наверное вы хотели написать `t[index] = new T()` или что-то такое. Только не называйте это синглтоном, синглтон - это одиночный инстанс, только один. Не два, не три, не четыре, а один. Назовите это `GenericPool`, будет правдоподобнее.

Comment: Вам уже [дали подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1258717/213987) насчёт статического поля-счётчика, но вы его не увидели и задаёте повторно вопрос без учёта этого совета. Давайте только не плодить дубли вопросов, отредактируйте текущий.